Executor distribution across nodes in a cluster
How are executors of a Spark application distributed across the nodes of a cluster? Let's say Spark is running in Cluster mode with YARN as the manager. The cluster is said to have 6 nodes, 16 cores each and 64GB mem. With the following configuration
--num-executors 10 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 16G
how does spark distribute these 10 executors across 6 nodes. few options that I can think of:

Does it only use 3 nodes(with 3 executors in each of them) + 1 node(only 1 executor in it)
4 nodes(with 2 executors in each of them) + 2 nodes(with one executor in each of them)
any other distribution?


First need to clarify the terminology
node - is physical machine, e.g. r6g.2xlarge in AWS
spark executor - is virtual machine which you set up via your spark config
core - is a smallest compute unit
spark executor config (--executor-cores, --executor-memory) cannot exceed physical node spec, e.g. you cannot specify --executor-cores 32 if your physical node has only 16 core
With your config --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 16G
you will result in 10 executors, each with 4 cores and 16G memory
it means that for 1 core - you allocate 4GB memory
and you will have 4 * 10 = 40 cores in total
When you submit spark job - execution dag is build. It splits to jobs, stages, tasks.
1 task will be run by 1 executor core
Lets say you have next code in spark
spark.read.parquet(...).repartition(200).write.mode(override).parquet(...)

after repartition you will have 200 tasks in Stage
you have 40 available cores which will run these 200 tasks in parallel
if partition distribution is same and physical machines are same, we can expect that each core will proceed 5 tasks sequentially
you have have 6 nodes, 16 cores each and 64GB mem each
with config --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 16G
I guess it will result in 3 executors per node. Because there is additional memory allocation for spark.executor.memoryOverhead
which has default value
executorMemory * spark.executor.memoryOverheadFactor, with minimum of 384
so, in total you can get 6 * 3 = 18 executors,
but, because you specified --num-executors 10 only 10 of them will be used by spark job

May be I was not clear in the question. I want to know how does spark distribute these 10 executors across 6 nodes. Does it only use 3 nodes(with 3 executors in each of them) + 1 node(only 1 executor in it) or 4 nodes(with 2 executors in each of them)  + 2 nodes(with one executor in each of them)
